# Why wired connection(Shared) blocks the internet from other Connections, Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, wifi, dns, networkmanager

I'm trying to share my wifi connection through ethernet in ubuntu and debian, but my script only work in ubuntu, when i use it in debian, the wired network works fine, but the wifi internet gets blocked (not the device, only the internet), i have these files: shared-network-config and myscript.sh

shared-network-config [file code]

```
[connection]
id=shared-network-config
uuid=51f018e3-2871-0e45-497e-9bbe6cebbe29
type=ethernet
permissions=

[ethernet]
mac-address=75-72-68-E9-E5-05
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=ignore
```

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
nmcli con up id 'MyWifiHome'
nmcli con up id 'shared-network-config'
```

After runs my script, the wired connection shared(shared-network-config) works fine, in the computer(client) and in the computer(server), but automatically blocks the internet form other connections like(MyWifiHome) in the computer(server) and the computer(client) can't have access to internet too.

Note: Im running debian 8.0.0 jessie,I already try in the Gui mode, but the problem persists, when i execute ping example.com, works fine only with the connection MyWifiHome, but when i connect to the conection shared-network-config for share the internet from MyWifiHome trought shared-network-config and i execute the command ping example.com returns this error: unknown host.

It's maybe a problem with the network priority of debian or dns?
Do you know any solution to my problem or other alternative?